# Create an image folder inside wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress

I have already set up a child theme. Is it possible to add via FTP on my server a folder (preferably into the same child theme folder) called `img` and then link to the images in that folder from my pages and posts?

I tried using this path:

```
<img src="../wp-content/themes/theme-child/img/placeholder.png"/>
```

but that did not work.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to do that yes. If you are having issues check you can reach the image by typing the full path into your address bar? (and try some other standard trouble shooting for missing images :) )

Comment: ok, i just want to be more specific:
Where are usually be stored by wordpress the pages tha an user creates?

Comment: If you create a page in the admin section of WordPress the information for that page would be stored in the Database, then will be displayed usually using single.php or page.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace with the following code

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/placeholder.png" />
```

Comment: This returns the URL of the parent theme.

Comment: For files in child theme use  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() instead of get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: This post doesn't answer correctly as says. get_template_directory_uri() Its calling core theme folder. Right answer is what @sheetal said.

Core Theme Folder: get_template_directory_uri();
Child Theme Folder: get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

Answer (score 12):

You need to use the stylesheet directory instead. With a child theme, if you use the template directory it will go to the parent (see explanation on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

It should be `<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/placeholder.png" />`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can then access it by doing...
get_template_directory_uri().'/img/placeholder.png'

Comment: Doing get_template_directory_uri().'/img/placeholder.png' where?

Pasting this into my page code?

Comment: Exactly... This will retreive the full path of the image you put in you newly created /img/ folder. In you example it woud give... `<img src="<?php template_directory_uri().'/img/placeholder.png' ?>" />`

Answer (score 0):

**Tested script**

```
src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/welcome.png" alt="">
```

See Reference [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

Answer (score 0):

You can create `img` folder inside your Child Theme directory and can access it via the same way as core/parent theme directory reference `get_template_directory_uri()`. This will return the Child Theme directory URI as you're referring this in Child Theme.

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/childthemeimage.png" alt="Child Theme Image">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
```

will return the URL of the child theme while

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```

Will return the parent theme URL